# With Ruby, where to use NOT, AND, OR, XOR operations for Fixnum or Bignum?

Tags: ruby, operators, bignum, fixnum

Just wondering if anyone has any realworld examples or know when you might use the NOT, AND, OR, XOR, <<, >> operators in Ruby.

I've been programming for 4 years and never come across the need to use any of these, wondering how common actual usage is & if its something I should fully understand.

Thanks,
-J

Answer (score 1):

`xor` (aka `^`), `<<`, and `>>` are more often used in lower-level programming. A C programmer will be intimately familiar with what these do. I'm writing an emulator in Ruby currently and use `<<` and `>>` often in the 6502 core due to things like it having a 1 byte word size but 2 byte pc. You need to do bit shifting to save the pc onto the stack, for example.

`not`, `and`, and `or` are variations of `!`, `&&`, and `||`, respectively. They work the same, but have a 'looser binding' to the variables around them. Their use (at least in practice) is to allow writing of expressions with fewer parens. I believe Rails actually forbids the use of these operators completely within its own codebase due to misunderstandings about how they work.

Comment: Very interesting, I think I'll give it a miss for now...if I need it on a project will come back to this stuff then. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In [an answer to another question](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2738249/take-most-significant-8-bytes-of-the-md5-hash-of-a-string-as-a-long-in-ruby/2739379#2739379), I was forced to do some bit-twiddling to work around a missing feature in the `String#unpack` / `Array#pack` pair of APIs. It uses left-shift (`<<`) and bitwise-or (`|`).